# Python - Setup a for or while loop for list of values and ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and sorry for asking this simple question. I have set of IDs and also range of IDs.My IDs looks like this,

```
IDs = [1,3:7,9,12:15]
```

I would like to have a for/while loop for IDs and print the ID,

For example:

```
for ID in IDs:
    print(ID)
```

I would like the print to be: 1,3,4,5,6,7,9,12,13,14,15. Is it possible? In the current form of IDs and for loop, it raises a syntax error at `3:4`.

Thanks!

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as a range of values in pure Python (with this syntax; of course there is `range(min, max)`). Are you sure this code doesn't raise an exception?

Comment: @pyPN I'm not sure what your question is exactly. As it is, your supplied code is invalid Python. Are you asking us for help debugging? Or are you asking us to write a solution for you?

Comment: @natiiix...sorry, my question was not a great, I have edited now.

Comment: @JordanSinger..I have edited the question. Basically, my inputs IDS will be a set of individual values and also range. I would like to use a loop and print individual ID numbers. In the current form, it raises error as `3:7` is not recognized.

Comment: @pyPN sure, I see. The problem is that `3:7` is not valid Python syntax. You may have gotten that from a language like R or Matlab. You'll need to use a slightly more complicated structure if you want to generate that on the fly, using `range` and list concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current input values, it is NOT possible to get the expected results as it is syntactically incorrect.

```
IDs = ['1','3:7','9','12:15'] # strings of value
res=[]
for i in IDs:
    if ':' in i:
        temp=i.split(':')
        res.extend(list(range(int(temp[0]), int(temp[1]) + 1)))
    else:
        res.append(int(i))

print(res)

[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: This solution is very unintuitive, especially for someone new to Python. Can you simplify this, or add some explanation about your steps?

Comment: @JordanSinger It is already simplified and cannot be simplified further. Thanks. You can ask specifically which part you do not understand I will try to answer that.

Comment: @mad_..Thanks! Your solution is great as well and I understand that you create an empty array and append as you loop through the `IDs`

Answer (score 1):

The input you provided is not a valid syntax. My answer assumes you can modify your input to something that makes sense, for example `[1, '3:7', 9, '12:15']`.

It is not bullet-proof but I'm sure it will lead you in the correct direction.

```
IDs = [1, '3:7', 9, '12:15']

output = []

for element in IDs:
    if isinstance(element, int):
        output.append(element)
    else:
        start, end = map(int, element.split(':'))
        output.extend(range(start, end + 1))

print(output)
# [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: @DeepSpace...Thanks! Yes, I can modify my input.